# Can a woman give gifts to non mahram man?

Tags: halal-haram, muslim-practices, men-women

A non mahram man helped a woman ,so the woman wants to give him a gift to thank him.

Can a woman give gifts to non mahram man and a man to non mahram woman?

Answer (score 1):

I personally didn't know this, but this link is what I am going to source from: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/300631/on-a-woman-giving-a-gift-to-a-non-mahram-man

Basically it is permissible for the basis that there is no bad intention or any concern that would lead to anything forbidden happening.